# Error with Web Links

Tags: error-warning

I recently noticed we have an error on our List of Link categories page (using Menu Item Type: List All Web Link Categories).  There are no errors in the log.  We are running php version 7.3.21 and Joomla! 3.9.20. Can anyone help with this?

```
Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /home/milfordu3a/public_html/components/com_weblinks/models/categories.php on line 95
```

Comment: So is a `null` result set being generated from a query? Are you able to provide any more diagnostic information?

Comment: One query returned 0 rows - there's not enough space in a comment to add it all

Comment: SELECT .....  FROM jos_fields AS a LEFT JOIN `jos_languages` AS l ... LEFT JOIN jos_users AS uc ...LEFT JOIN jos_viewlevels AS ag...LEFT JOIN jos_users AS ua ... LEFT JOIN jos_fields_groups AS g ...WHERE a.context = 'com_weblinks.categories' ...

Comment: I did notice that com_weblinks isn't in any of the tables this query uses so could that be it?

Comment: Please add all relevant details to your question as an [edit].

Answer (score 3):

This is a reported issue which can be seen [in the tracker](https://issues.joomla.org/tracker/joomla-cms/23172).

> **Steps to reproduce the issue**
>
> 1. Install Weblinks 3.6.0 Package from
>    https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/official-extensions/weblinks/
>    on Joomla 3.9.0 using PHP 7.2 and set to report PHP warnings.
> 2. Go to Components - Web Links and add any URL as New Web Link to the existing category Uncategorised with default options, Save & Close.
> 3. Create a new menu item and select Web Links - List All Web Link Categories with default options, Save & Close.
> 4. Go to the front end and select the new link.
>
> **Expected result**
>
> The list shows the category Uncategorised.
>
> **Actual result**
>
> > Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\www\joomla380\components\com_weblinks\models\categories.php on line 95
>
> The list shows the category Uncategorised.
>
> **System information (as much as possible)**
>
> Joomla 3.9.0
>
> PHP 7.2.11
>
> **Additional comments**
>
> Fixed by inserting the following lines before line 95 in components/com_weblinks/models/categories.php
>
> ```
>   if (!is_array($this->_items)) {
>       $this->_items = array();
>   }
> ```
>
> Ref. topic "Weblinks Categories page - Warning: count()" at https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=715&t=967481

Comment: Your post was flagged by the system as Low Quality.  Please avoid posting pure hyperlink answers.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it :-)